# Cannot find Manifest and Java files in Android Studio 4.0.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've installed Android Studio 4.0.1 today and started to learn Android programming therefore I made a new project ,but I can't find the *manifests* and *java* folders as are shown in previous versions' tutorials.

[Android Studio 4.0.1 (My PC)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IphFj.png) ,
[Android Studio 3.6.1 (Tutorial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70zoZ.png)

So it made me confuse.
Now, how should I deal with this form of packaging?
Can I change it to the previous versions' settings?

Comment: It look like there are some issues in your project. Once you build the project successfully, you will see the correct structure

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I chose the project's name, selected "Java" as the app's language, the minimum version of the Android which I want to run my app and selected "Blank Activity" as the teacher said in the tutorial but, there are differences in my project style and his.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed AS 2.33 Bundle while the system was connected to the internet. It downloaded Gradle and the project was started as I wanted.

I've got a lot of problems with downloading the sdk caused by the sanctions against Iran, but with Bundle, I get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you install the Android studio it will also download plugins, sdk, gradle and other tools necessary to develop an android application.
My guess is that when downloading maybe the internet connection is off.
Try to reinstall the studio with standard settings and also don't import previous settings.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well today, I would suggest you reinstall the Android Studio again but don't turn off your internet connection while it is installing, and please don't copy the previous settings which you installed in your earlier version.

Comment: I reinstalled AS4 and didn't turn off the internet connection but everything is same as before.